# Souce Sans Pro Fonts not working on development Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fonts, asset-pipeline, assets

I'm building a rails app and it needs to use the `Source Sans Pro` font. I can't import the font in HTML tag (because this process increases the page loading times), to do it, i've downloaded the `.ttf` fonts of in google fonts sites (only the regular, light and semibold fonts).

The font just not working, the fallback `sans serif` is executing, i've put the `ttf's` files in `app/assets/fonts/` dir, added to my `assets.rb` the following code:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts", "node_modules")

Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)\z/
```

In my `app/assets/stylesheets/_fonts.scss` i have the following code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  src: asset-url('SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf');
  src: asset-url('SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf') format('ttf'),
       asset-url('SourceSansPro-Light.ttf') format('ttf'),
       asset-url('SourceSansPro-SemiBold.ttf') format('ttf');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

in a `global.scss` file, i have:

```
* {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
```

all the `.scss` files are imported in a `application.scss` file:

```
@import 'fonts';
@import 'base/globals.scss';
```

In the browser console, no one error are displayed, but when the template renders, the font `Source Sans Pro` not works, and the fallback `sans-serif` are rendered. Please, how can i right import and use the google downloaded fonts?

Comment: Is there any reason you would wanna use the font directly in the asset pipeline?

You could just add the google fonts link to your `src: google_font_link` and i think it will stil compile with your styles

Comment: The reason is the time to load the font, if i add the font to my asset pipeline, the time to load page will be faster to load

Comment: Yes I understand that, but what I'm saying is, you add the link not to the head but to the `_font.scss` file it'll compile and then it'll be cached so it's always part of the assets after the first compile and the load time reduces after the very first compile.

`@font-face {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  src: "https:googlefonts/sourcesanslink.ttf";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Font formats (EOT, TTF, WOFF, SVG, WOFF2...) There are so many choices! Unfortunately, despite the huge variety of formats, there isn’t a single one that works in all browsers. What does this mean? That you'll have to make use of multiple font formats to deliver a consistent experience. [reference from this link](https://creativemarket.com/blog/the-missing-guide-to-font-formats)

Here is couple of steps to setup google font (including corrections for your setting)

1. put 3 fonts file (eot, svg and ttf) in app/assets/fonts/ notes: Unfortunately Google just provide ttf from [google font web](https://fonts.google.com/), but you can download through [github raw](https://github.com/google/fonts/) or through [google font heroku apps](http://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/) choose font name and download , here is [link source sans pro](http://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts/source-sans-pro?subsets=latin)
2. call the font file with this scss (for example app/assets/stylesheets/fonts.scss), **here your setting different**.

   ```
   @font-face {
       font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
       src: asset-url('source-sans-pro-v11-latin-regular.eot');
       src: asset-url('source-sans-pro-v11-latin-regular.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
              asset-url('source-sans-pro-v11-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'),
              asset-url('source-sans-pro-v11-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
              asset-url('source-sans-pro-v11-latin-regular.svg#Source Sans Pro') format('svg');
       font-weight: normal;
       font-style: normal;
   }
   ```
3. Call font-family name from your other class (base/globals.scss)

   ```
   * {
     font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
   }
   ```
4. do the import through your app/assets/application.scss (here two corrections for your problem don't use _fonts.scss but fonts.scss and import with fonts.scss instead fonts)

   ```
   @import 'fonts.scss';
   # make sure your call fonts.scss first before you use it
   @import 'base/globals.scss';
   ```